# DQL - fetching related entities

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, dql

Normally I would just lazy load my entities but right now I need to create a DQL thats able to fetch nodes as an array. I have tried several queries but I can't get it to work, below is two example:

```
// example one
$this->em->createQuery('SELECT n FROM Entities\Node n WHERE n.nodeType INSTANCE OF ?1')
    ->setParameter(1, $type)->getArrayResult();
// example two
$this->em->createQuery('SELECT n FROM Entities\Node n WHERE n.nodeType_id = ?1')
    ->setParameter(1, $type->id)->getArrayResult();
```

Im not sure what INSTANCE OF actually does but it didn't work, using nodeType_id didn't work either because my annotation doesn't have an nodeType_id only the database table does.

So what is the right approach for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to use an equal sign like this:

```
$this->em->createQuery('SELECT n FROM Entities\Node n WHERE n.nodeType = ?1')
    ->setParameter(1, $type->id)->getArrayResult();
```

where type is another entity.

Comment: If your answer works - great! If you need other conditions on the nodeType then the more general case is to use a join: `'SELECT n FROM Entities\Node n JOIN n.nodeType nt WHERE nt.id = ?1' and nt.someOtherProperty = ?2'`

Answer (score 2):

What is nodeType? If it's just a string then you only need:

```
$this->em
    ->createQuery('SELECT n FROM Entities\Node n WHERE n.nodeType = ?1')
    ->setParameter(1, $type)
    ->getArrayResult();
```

If you're using inheritance and you want Nodes of a specific type then use:

```
$this->em
    ->createQuery("SELECT n FROM Entities\Node n WHERE n INSTANCE OF $type")
    ->getArrayResult();
```

Note $type should be something like : `$type = 'Entities\Nodes\NodeSubclass'`. You can't add it as a parameter.

Comment: NodeType is another entity, I have a ManyToOne relation between node and nodeType